# get selected form_dropdown codeigniter from database

Tags: codeigniter

i am new with codeigniter, and i am trying to set selected value from database,

this code doesn't work,

```
<?php 

     $options = array(
      'one'  => 'one',
      'two'  => 'two',
     );

     $selected = $teach->number;

     echo form_dropdown('number', $options, $selected); 
?>
```

but when i try to manual, it work.

```
<?php 

     $options = array(
      'one'  => 'one',
      'two'  => 'two',
     );

     $selected = 'one';

     echo form_dropdown('number', $options, $selected); 
?>
```

I don't know why,
Any advice would be great. Thanks

---

this my controller

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->data['teach'] = $this->EditTeachModel->getPosts(); // calling Post model method getPosts()
    $this->data['singleTeach'] = $this->EditTeachModel->getPostsId($id); // calling Post model method getPosts()

    //view
    $this->load->view('edit_teach', $this->data); // load the view file , we are passing $data array to view file
}

public function update(){
    $id = $this->input->post('kd');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data = array(
        'kd' => $this->input->post('kd'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
        'number' => $this->input->post('number'),
        'pass' => $this->input->post('pass')
    );
    $this->EditTeachModel->updatePosts($id, $data); 

    $this->index();


}
```

This my model

```
public function getPosts(){
    $this->db->from('teach');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}

public function getPostsId($data){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('teach');
    $this->db->where('kd', $data);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}

public function updatePosts($id, $data){
    $this->db->where('kd', $id);
    $this->db->update('teach', $data);
}
```

this my view

```
<?php foreach($singleTeach as $teach) {?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() . "edit_teach/update"?>">
    <div class="card-body"><td>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="kd">Kode :</label>
              <input type="text" id="kd" name="kd" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $teach->kd; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="name">Nama:</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $teach->name; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="date">Date :</label>
              <input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $teach->date; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <?php echo form_label('Number '); ?> <?php echo form_error('number'); ?>
              <?php 
                  $options = array(
                  'one'         => 'one',
                  'two'         => 'two',
                  );

                  $selected = $teach->number;
                  print_r($teach);

                 echo form_dropdown('number', $options, $selected); 
                ?> 
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label id="pass">Password :</label>
                <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $teach->pass; ?>">
             </div>
            </div>
             </div>
         </div>
        <!-- /.card-body -->

       <div class="card-footer">
          <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit','class'=> 'btn btn-primary', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>
       </div>
      </form>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: make sure `$teach->number` has the key part of `$options` array

Comment: @pradeep yes of course, $teach->number has the same value between $options array.

Comment: can your show your `$teach` data `print_r($teach);`

Comment: stdClass Object ( [kd] => 20104D18 [name] => jad [date] => 2000-09-11 [number] => one [pass] => 123456 )

Comment: its pretty simple thing , it should work, also make sure your `$options` array's key should not have any space, blank or anything, can you show your full form code

Comment: @pradeep yes of course.

Comment: i checked and its working for me : see this :; https://imgur.com/pWgR5uJ, there must be something else which causing this

Comment: show me the output of `print_r($this->data['singleTeach']);`

Comment: @pradeep Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [kd] => 20104D18 [name] => jad [date] => 2000-09-11 [number] => one [pass] => 123456 )

Comment: @pradeep i didn't realize, when i check my database, field status with max char length 20. so there have any space with my value "one      ". so i changed max char length, finally it works. Thankyou